# Start & Stop Timer

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I have a timer that calls a function every 10 seconds:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkForMessages)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

It calls the function:

```
- (void)checkForMessages
{

    //do something here

}
```

Two questions:

1. How do I stop the timer if needed?
2. Can I put this timer and function somewhere so that I can call it from different view controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval`" returns an "`NSTimer`" object.

If you hold onto that object (e.g. set and get it via a "`property`"), you can stop it via the [NSTimer `invalidate` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTimer/invalidate).

And since you're asking for code, add this to your view controller's .h @interface:

```
@property (strong) NSTimer * messageTimer;
```

Then, in your view controller's .m file:

```
self.messageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(checkForMessages)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

Makes sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense.  So to stop the timer you would?

Comment: I guess something like this? [messageTimer invalidate]; self. messageTimer = nil;

Comment: Something isn't right with the way I'm invalidating.  It doesn't seem to be stopping the timer.  Any ideas why?

Comment: set a breakpoint on the invalidate and make sure that the "`NSTimer`" object is the same as the one that you created.

Comment: It's all the same messageTimer and I set a breakpoint but don't see anything out of line.  Thoughts?